# Refreshing and preserving crackers

Tags: food

After opening a packet of crackers, I store in a zip-lock bag to keep them from getting moist. But that's not good enough, and they still lose their crispness.

What’s a good way to refresh them?

What’s a better way to keep them once opened?

If it matters, these are Pepperide Farm butter crackers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a toaster oven, you can lay them on a metal tray or a sheet of aluminum foil, and toast them for 1-2 minutes. Only toast the ones you're planning to eat right then.

I've done this with older corn chips. I assume it will work just as well with crackers!

Answer (score 1):

There are [commercial cracker storage containers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IXRI0Q8) made out of heavier polyethylene, or of polypropylene (which is dish-washer safe). The problem with thinner polyethylene plastic bags is that there is some [permeability to water vapor.](http://www.evergreen-packaging.com/en/ShowNews.asp?id=70)

You can improve upon these by putting in a packet of silica gel water absorbent; the silica can be regenerated by *gentle* heating in an oven.

You might also try reusing the aluminum-foil lined zipper-locking plastic bags from large coffee packages. The aluminum layer is particularly impermeable to air and water vapor! Note that these bags often have a one-way valve to allow removing air. This may be an asset or hindrance -- if the crackers don't stay crisp, try taping over the valve.

[image: coffee packaging]

Answer (score 0):

After I open them, I put my crackers and chips in the freezer. They stay fresh much longer there; weeks if not months.